How to project the solution of a linear ODE to a specified Eigen subspace

Let $\mathbf{x}(t), \mathbf{x}_0, \mathbf{x}_1 \in \mathbb{R}^n$ be a trajectory, initial state, and target state, respectively.
Let $\frac{\mathrm{d} \mathbf{x}(t)}{\mathrm{d} t} = \mathbf{v}(\mathbf{x}(t)) = -\mathbf{A} (\mathbf{x}(t) - \mathbf{x}_1)$ where $\mathbf{A} = \mathbf{A}^\top \in \mathbb{R}^{n \times n}$ is a symmetric matrix. E.g. $\mathbf{A}$ could be the Hessian of some potential function.
We know the solution to this ODE is $\mathbf{x}(t) = \mathbf{x}_1 + \exp(-\mathbf{A} t)(\mathbf{x}_0 - \mathbf{x}_1)$.
The Eigen decomposition $\mathbf{A} = \mathbf{Q} \mathbf{\Lambda} \mathbf{Q}^{-1}$ gives an orthogonal matrix of eigenvectors such that $\mathbf{Q}^{-1} = \mathbf{Q}^\top$.
Construct a matrix of Eigen vectors with positive Eigen values $\mathbf{R} = [\mathbf{Q}_{i,j} | \lambda_i > 0]$.
Since the Eigen vector matrix is orthogonal, it serves as an orthonormal basis and we can construct a projection matrix $\mathbf{P} = \mathbf{R}\mathbf{R}^\top$ that projects vectors to the subspace spanned by the Eigen vectors corresponding to positive Eigen values.

Given unprojected initial and target states, $\mathbf{x}_0$ and $\mathbf{x}_1$, how can I obtain a trajectory in the specified subspace? Computing $\mathbf{x}(t)$ results in infinite values or NaNs, so projecting the solution itself does not seem to be an option.

What do you mean by $x(t)$ containing infinite values ? How is that possible if $x(t) = x_1 + exp(-At)(x_0 - x_1)$ which is finite.

Since $\mathbf{A}$ has some negative Eigen values, $\mathbf{x}(t)$ quickly explodes as time progresses. I am just interested in solution within the stable subspace.

If you place yourself in the eigenbasis and consider $\Lambda$ being diagonal with the $k$ positive eigenvalues on the diagonal followed by the $n-k$ negative eigenvalues then the looking at the $k$ first entries and setting the $n-k$ other values to $0$ will give you the projection on that subspace. Then change the coordinates back to the canonical basis. Shouldn't that solve your issue ?

Do you want to know specifically how to project an ODE onto a basis or how to solve this terminal value(?) problem? Because it isn't clear to me that your proposed steps solve the problem in any meaningful way but it also isn't clear what the overall objective is.
